# angular4.x docs for offline reading

Tags: angular

I wanted to  know how to get the angular 4.x docs offline.

I have cloned the [angular repo](https://github.com/angular/angular) from github.
I ran `yarn` into `aio` directory(as mentioned in their [README](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/aio)).

However it gives me following error

```
yarn install v0.27.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
$ uglifyjs node_modules/lunr/lunr.js -c -m -o src/assets/js/lunr.min.js --source-map
fs.js:652
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^

TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:652:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1299:33)
    at /Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/directory-encoder/node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs:311:12
    at /Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/directory-encoder/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:188:33
    at /Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/directory-encoder/node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs:254:9
    at tryToString (fs.js:513:3)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:501:12)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Then I ran `yarn docs` and it gave me following output:

```
yarn docs v0.27.5

$ rimraf src/generated/{docs,*.json}
$ dgeni ./tools/transforms/angular.io-package
info:    running processor: readFilesProcessor
info:    running processor: extractJSDocCommentsProcessor
info:    running processor: collectExamples
info:    running processor: readTypeScriptModules
info:    running processor: linkInheritedDocs
info:    running processor: parseTagsProcessor
info:    running processor: extractTagsProcessor
info:    running processor: codeNameProcessor
info:    running processor: createOverviewDump
info:    running processor: convertPrivateClassesToInterfacesProcessor
info:    running processor: mergeDecoratorDocs
info:    running processor: extractDecoratedClassesProcessor
info:    running processor: markBarredODocsAsPrivate
info:    running processor: computeIdsProcessor
info:    running processor: filterContainedDocs
info:    running processor: filterPrivateDocs
info:    running processor: simplifyMemberAnchors
info:    running processor: computePathsProcessor
info:    running processor: generateApiListDoc
info:    running processor: addNotYetDocumentedProperty
info:    running processor: matchUpDirectiveDecorators
info:    running processor: processNavigationMap
info:    running processor: renderDocsProcessor
info:    running processor: unescapeCommentsProcessor
info:    running processor: inlineTagProcessor
info:    running processor: renderExamples
info:    running processor: copyContentAssetsProcessor
info:    running processor: postProcessHtml
info:    running processor: computeSearchTitleProcessor
info:    running processor: generateKeywordsProcessor
info:    running processor: checkUnbalancedBackTicks
info:    running processor: fixInternalDocumentLinks
info:    running processor: checkAnchorLinksProcessor
warn:    Dangling Links Found in "guide/aot-compiler.json":
 - generated/zips/toh-pt6/toh-pt6.zip
warn:    Dangling Links Found in "guide/quickstart.json":
 - generated/zips/cli-quickstart/cli-quickstart.zip
warn:    Dangling Links Found in "guide/webpack.json":
 - generated/zips/webpack/webpack.zip
warn:    Dangling Links Found in "docs.json":
 - generated/live-examples/quickstart/eplnkr.html
error:   Error: 4 unmatched links
    at Object.$process (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/dgeni-packages/base/processors/checkAnchorLinks.js:106:17)
    at /Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/dgeni/lib/Dgeni.js:179:54
    at _fulfilled (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:604:44
    at runSingle (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
error:   Error processing docs:  Error: 4 unmatched links
    at Object.$process (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/dgeni-packages/base/processors/checkAnchorLinks.js:106:17)
    at /Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/dgeni/lib/Dgeni.js:179:54
    at _fulfilled (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:604:44
    at runSingle (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:155
                throw e;
                ^

Error: 4 unmatched links
    at Object.$process (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/dgeni-packages/base/processors/checkAnchorLinks.js:106:17)
    at /Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/dgeni/lib/Dgeni.js:179:54
    at _fulfilled (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:604:44
    at runSingle (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

So does somebody know a way around it? I just wanted to get the docs for offline reading.

**Edit**: 
Following @gavlan's response and downgrading yarn to v0.24.6, here is my output:

```
yarn install v0.24.6
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
$ uglifyjs node_modules/lunr/lunr.js -c -m -o src/assets/js/lunr.min.js --source-map
✨  Done in 2.75s.
```

Hence running `yarn` gives no error and executes fine.

However running `yarn docs still gives error

```
yarn docs v0.24.6
$ rimraf src/generated/{docs,*.json}
$ dgeni ./tools/transforms/angular.io-package
info:    running processor: readFilesProcessor
info:    running processor: extractJSDocCommentsProcessor
info:    running processor: collectExamples
info:    running processor: readTypeScriptModules
info:    running processor: linkInheritedDocs
info:    running processor: parseTagsProcessor
info:    running processor: extractTagsProcessor
info:    running processor: codeNameProcessor
info:    running processor: createOverviewDump
info:    running processor: convertPrivateClassesToInterfacesProcessor
info:    running processor: mergeDecoratorDocs
info:    running processor: extractDecoratedClassesProcessor
info:    running processor: markBarredODocsAsPrivate
info:    running processor: computeIdsProcessor
info:    running processor: filterContainedDocs
info:    running processor: filterPrivateDocs
info:    running processor: simplifyMemberAnchors
info:    running processor: computePathsProcessor
info:    running processor: generateApiListDoc
info:    running processor: addNotYetDocumentedProperty
info:    running processor: matchUpDirectiveDecorators
info:    running processor: processNavigationMap
info:    running processor: renderDocsProcessor
info:    running processor: unescapeCommentsProcessor
info:    running processor: inlineTagProcessor
info:    running processor: renderExamples
info:    running processor: copyContentAssetsProcessor
info:    running processor: postProcessHtml
info:    running processor: computeSearchTitleProcessor
info:    running processor: generateKeywordsProcessor
info:    running processor: checkUnbalancedBackTicks
info:    running processor: fixInternalDocumentLinks
info:    running processor: checkAnchorLinksProcessor
warn:    Dangling Links Found in "guide/aot-compiler.json":
 - generated/zips/toh-pt6/toh-pt6.zip
warn:    Dangling Links Found in "guide/quickstart.json":
 - generated/zips/cli-quickstart/cli-quickstart.zip
warn:    Dangling Links Found in "guide/webpack.json":
 - generated/zips/webpack/webpack.zip
warn:    Dangling Links Found in "docs.json":
 - generated/live-examples/quickstart/eplnkr.html
error:   Error: 4 unmatched links
    at Object.$process (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/dgeni-packages/base/processors/checkAnchorLinks.js:106:17)
    at /Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/dgeni/lib/Dgeni.js:179:54
    at _fulfilled (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:604:44
    at runSingle (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
error:   Error processing docs:  Error: 4 unmatched links
    at Object.$process (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/dgeni-packages/base/processors/checkAnchorLinks.js:106:17)
    at /Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/dgeni/lib/Dgeni.js:179:54
    at _fulfilled (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:604:44
    at runSingle (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:155
                throw e;
                ^

Error: 4 unmatched links
    at Object.$process (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/dgeni-packages/base/processors/checkAnchorLinks.js:106:17)
    at /Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/dgeni/lib/Dgeni.js:179:54
    at _fulfilled (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:604:44
    at runSingle (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/Users/apple/code/angular/aio/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Did you try to run "yarn" before "yarn docs"?

Comment: @galvan yes, and I just updated the question and added its output.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is due to a bug in yarn@>=0.25.4 that may install wrong versions in node_mdules/.bin/. It has been fixed with yarnpkg/yarn#3877 and should be included in the 0.28.1 release.

Try updating your yarn and run the command again.
For more info you can check the [official issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18488) in angular project

Comment: I've updated my post and included output after downgrading yarn to 0.24.6